# How to retrieve data from access database(.accdb) into excel using vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, adodb

I'm working on Excel VBA macros and I want to retrieve data from a MS Access database (`.accdb` file).

I've tried using below connection string and it throws runtime error '438'

```
   Dim cn As Object, rs As Object,DBFullName As String,Target As Range
   DBFullName = "D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.accdb"
   Set Target = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"

   Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   rs.Open "SELECT * FROM test", cn, , , adCmdText

  For int i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
  Target.Offset(1, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
  Next
  Target.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
```

PLease help me to resolve the error

Comment: You say it's an `.accdb` file - then why are you usnig an `.mdb` extension in your connection string?? `DBFullName = "D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb"` ??

Comment: .mdb is a typo it is .accdb

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried using below connection string and it throws runtime error '438'

`Run-time error: '438'` means that the `Object doesn't support this property or method..`

You are getting that error because you are mixing `VB.Net` with `VBA`

This

```
For int i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
```

should be

```
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
```

Beside the above, I guess `DBFullName = "D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb"` is a typo from your end as you are using `.Accdb`?

Comment: yes .mdb is a typo. How to resolve this error do i need to add any reference

Comment: I tried the above code and it is working fine for the database I have. I doubt about the data in the database. Try this recordset open command: rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Books", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: I am Not user2514925

Comment: @BalasubramaniyanRamadoss: I didn't understand your comment then :)

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout: I don't get any error while trying the above given code with different database.

Comment: @BalasubramaniyanRamadoss: The error is becuase of what i mentioned in my post above :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.  Drop the WHERE clause if you don't want to apply a filter.

Also, set a reference to:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

```
Sub Select_From_Access()
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Dim DBFullName As String
    Dim TargetRange As Range

    DBFullName = "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Nwind_Sample.mdb"

    'On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set TargetRange = Sheets("Select").Range("A1")

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [OrderDetails] WHERE [OrderID] = 10248", cn, , , adCmdText

    ' Write the field names
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    TargetRange.Offset(1, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    ' Write recordset
    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```